# Websockets always fail on handshake - 404

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket, jwt

Server side: Spring boot + JWT Auth
Client: React app

I want to connect via websocket but whenever I try to do it I always get error in console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:6060/ws/app/add' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Backend:
1) Websocket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:6060")
            .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:8082")
  //                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy()))
                .withSockJS();
        registry.addEndpoint("/add");
    }

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

}

2) Controller for receiving:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/send") // FROM FRONTEND TO HERE
    @SendTo("/topic/public") // FROM HERE TO FRONTEND
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        return chatMessage;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/add")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                               SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        // Add username in web socket session
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        return chatMessage;


    }
}
```

3) Security Config

```
package com.winterrent.winterrent.configuration;

import com.winterrent.winterrent.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.winterrent.winterrent.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import com.winterrent.winterrent.service.user.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/ws/**")
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

4) JWT Auth filter

```
package com.winterrent.winterrent.security;

import com.winterrent.winterrent.service.user.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * JWT token got from the request, validated and based on it loads the user associated with the token and pass
 * it to Spring Security
 */
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        LOGGER.debug(request.getHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"));
        if (Objects.nonNull(request.getHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"))) {
            bearerToken = request.getHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol");
            return bearerToken.substring(15, bearerToken.length());
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

5) CORS settings

```
package com.winterrent.winterrent.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:6060")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8082")
//                .allowedOrigins("*")

                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
 const wsx123 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:6060/ws/app/add',
            ['Authorization', window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')], ['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true']);
```

I tried many options, but really always 404... 
Has anybody any idea?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with really bad path (404 was not stupid error) -

```
'ws://localhost:6060/resources/ws'
```

Above was correct because I had resources context path set up.